# Are blank pet passports available outside of the EU?

Tags: travel, vaccination

In Europe vaccination history and pertaining information about your pet are collected in his pet passport. Now we moved away from Europe and are about to get another pet (in addition to the ones we brought with us).

The problem is: The EU only sells passports to veterinary doctors (even though the passports apparently serve no other purpose than the person's convenience). But collecting vaccination information in the form of loose sheets of paper is ridiculous! Let alone the fact that the microchip info etc. is missing.

So my question is:

Can I order pet passports online?

I don't care if it's made in China and is a fake.

[Click here if you don't know what I'm talking about](https://www.google.com/search?q=eu+heimtier+ausweis&es_sm=91&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=BLdMVaH8J6GnmAXQqoAw&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1367&bih=651).

Comment: I saw [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/PRESTIN-Pet-Credentials/dp/B0083Y0TKG) but it's not available and also I wouldn't buy something if I can't look inside first.

Comment: I also found [this](http://www.pettravelstore.com/pet-passport-medical-record/) but I do think that 25 dollars is on the expensive side.

Comment: I edited your question since shopping questions aren't allowed on this site, please feel free to edit again if you feel that I changed the meaning of your question.

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions some are available [commercially for less than a dollar](http://www.drsfostersmith.com/product/prod_display.cfm?pcatid=750) There is even a least one [free version](http://www.freeprintablemedicalforms.com/preview/Pet_Health_Record) All you really need is a note book.

As all posts to Pets.SE are licensed [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) maybe someone will post an answer with all the fields that everyone can print and use.